# vscode won't open on mac anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have used vscode for some time now and was using it as root - I know I shouldn't have been but didn't know the reason until recently.

for some time code would start and open to a blank page. Running code --disable-extensions worked a few times so I kept using this.

Now however nothing seems to get it running. I ran code --verbose and got the following output.

```
[main 10:19:03 AM] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 10:19:03 AM] Resolved machine identifier: f83dc69140adei345i567ijbusv9676bfgsf35b1fb49bac751ab456542fba
[main 10:19:03 AM] update#setState idle
2018-05-21 10:19:04.025 Electron[14154:178705] *** WARNING: Textured window <AtomNSWindow: 0x7ff0b9836c30> is getting an implicitly transparent titlebar. This will break when linking against newer SDKs. Use NSWindow's -titlebarAppearsTransparent=YES instead.
¢[14154:0521/101914.882321:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Loading "vs/workbench/workbench.main" failed", source: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js (7)
[14154:0521/101914.882424:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Detail: ", source: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js (7)
[14154:0521/101914.882478:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.js'", source: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js (7)
[14154:0521/101914.882528:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Here are the modules that depend on it:", source: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js (7)
[14154:0521/101914.882572:INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "===anonymous1===", source: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/loader.js (7)
¢›3434[main 10:19:33 AM] update#checkForUpdates, state =  idle
[main 10:19:33 AM] update#setState checking for updates
[main 10:19:35 AM] update#setState idle
[14154:0521/101945.768309:INFO:CONSOLE(80)] "Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Code/clp'

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Code/clp'", source: file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js (80)`
```

Also, when I run the above I get a process that takes up massive amounts of CPU - sometimes up to 250%.

[image]

code is being run by my local user account.

I have tried uninstalling vscode by deleting it in Applications, deleting .vscode from my user directory and deleting Code from ~/Library/Application Support/ and then re-installing. Same issue after reinstall.

Any solutions or even ideas on a fix?